# iOS 5: Is it possible to write a struct to a plist file?

Tags: iphone, ios, file, struct, plist

I have a struct as defined by the following:

```
typedef struct {
    NSString *SportName;
    NSInteger numberOfPeriods;
    CFTimeInterval periodLength;
    NSString *periodName;
    CFTimeInterval secondaryClockTime;
    NSString *LeftSecondaryCounterName;
    NSString *RightSecondaryCounterName;
    bool PossessionArrow;
} GamePreset;
```

Is it possible to write variables of type GamePreset to a plist file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in support for writing an arbitrary `struct` as a property list.  You have to write a method that converts the struct to a property list.

In theory, you could do it at run-time by parsing the result of `@encode(GamePreset)`, which is replaced (at compile-time) by a string describing `GamePreset`:

```
NSLog(@"encode = %s", @encode(GamePreset));
...
2012-03-04 00:57:43.456 encodetest[43337:903] encode = {?=@qd@d@@B}
```

This has serious drawbacks.  One is that you don't get the field names, so your plist won't be particularly useful unless the reader knows the `struct` format, and any change to the `struct`'s layout will make saved plists unreadable.

Another big drawback is that the `@encode` string doesn't have any information about structure padding.  You have to account for it when parsing the string.  I think you can use [`NSGetSizeAndAlignment`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSGetSizeAndAlignment) to help with this.

If you want to risk your sanity and try this, read the [“Type Encodings” section of the *Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html).

I recommend you just bite the bullet and write a simple function that takes a `GamePreset *` and returns an `NSDictionary *` using hardcoded knowledge of the structure layout.

Comment: Looks like encoding it as a string would be about **10 times** as hard as just writing a `- (NSDictionary *) DictionaryFromGamePreset:(GamePreset)NewGamePreset` command... Oh well.